# Matching All Substrings in JSGF Grammar

Tags: speech-recognition, grammar, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am using a jsgf format grammar with pocketsphinx. I want to be able to match/recognise a only a finite number of possible input sentences (i.e. a command and control type interface).

However, due to the nature of these “valid” sentences, and sentence fragment (sub-sentence) with three or more words is also a valid input.

For example, if the valid sentences are:

- This is a valid sentence
- So is this one

then the grammar should contain:

- This is a
- This is a valid
- This is a valid sentence
- is a valid
- is a valid sentence
- a valid sentence
- So is this
- So is this one
- is this one

*[Obviously, in this example, this grammar seems a bit bizarre, but it does make sense in the language/context I am using.]*

Is there any way this can be done automatically using jsgf grammar syntax or any pocketsphinx / CMU Sphinx tool. Of course I could programmatically generate a grammar file given a set of valid full sentences, but this seems a bit long-winded and makes the grammar file long and difficult to edit directly (or even just to determine what the valid full sentences are).

The best I can come up with just using the rules of the jsgf format (that I know of) is the following. (For the example above:)

```
<a> = this is a;
<valid> = (<a> | is a) valid;
<sentence> = (<valid> | a valid) sentence;

<this> = so is this;
<one> = (<this> | is this) one;
```

(E.g. the rule  matches any sub-sentence of length three or more which ends with the word “valid”.)

This grammar contains exactly the valid strings listed above. Nevertheless, this grammar still needs to be generated programmatically from the set of valid full sentences, so I may as well list all sub-sentences explicitly. This format does however make it slightly easier to see directly from the jsgf file what the valid full sentences are.

Essentially, my question is: Is there a better way to achieve the above grammar with pocketsphinx?

Answer (score 0):

And it is not the task of the grammar to enforce complex contstrains in recognized speech. When you restrict things in the grammar, recognition becomes much slower and prone to mistakes because users do not follow the grammars as you envision. To build a proper application you need to use a free-form grammar that allows to recognize speech properly and build a post-processor for that. Post-processor can use regular expressions or even some custom code to verify the requirements you need.

This should work:

```
 <sentence> = this | is  | a | valid | sentence | one | so;
```

If you need something more advanced, you can build a bigram langauge model and convert it to fsg like in [librispeech paper](https://www.danielpovey.com/files/2015_icassp_librispeech.pdf) on Figure 1.

Also answered on [Sourceforge Forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/6961a8a4b6/?limit=25)